# coldfusion onrequestend.cfm

Tags: coldfusion

Is there a way to make `onrequestend.cfm` call conditional.
i.e if I call a template through ajax, I don't want that `onrequestend.cfm` should be executed on ajax requests.

As in my case this is generating some header info like meta tags etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a few options:

- Place a blank onRequestEnd.cfm in the directory containing the AJAX services you're connecting to, as Daniel recommends.
- Switch to Application.cfc and the `onRequestEnd()` event instead of onRequestEnd.cfm; and inside your `onRequestStart()` event method, tell ColdFusion not to do anything for the onRequestEnd event.

Since you didn't specify, I'll guess and say that your AJAX requests use a CFC, like so:

```
/foo/bar.cfc?method=getSomething&param=value
```

In which case, you can easily identify all requests being routed to a CFC like this:

```
function onRequestStart(targetPath){
    if (listLast(arguments.targetPath, ".") eq "cfc"){
        structDelete(this, "onRequestEnd");
    }
}
```

Note that the function is only deleted **for the current request**, so you don't have to worry about it not being there for future requests. It will be.

Answer (score 0):

There is not that I am aware of. However if you place all the templates you will be calling in a sub-directory and place a blank onRequestEnd.cfm in the sub-directory that should give you the same effect.

Comment: Coul you not put some conditional logic in the onRequestEnd.cfm which would determine the ajax pages?  I prefix my ajax templates with ajax_ I would imageine FindNoCase(cgi.script_name,'ajax_',1) might do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

We handle this with URL variables. Call any page with

```
?NoHeaderFooter=true
```

and then conditional logic in onRequestStart like this:

```
<cfif NOT StructKeyExists(URL,"NoHeaderFooter")>
output header/footer etc. here
</cfif>
```

Can be used in both onRequestStart and onRequestEnd or create two variables so you can control each. Then all our ajax calls submit to something like:

```
report/FormController.cfc?Method=DoSomething&NoHeaderFooter=true
```